# About the Licence of Shared Codes on the Kaggle Site

Tags: kaggle, code

I have one job offer and there are many codes on the Kaggle site based of that job offer which could be used for the company usage like the result of [this google search](https://www.google.com/search?q=site%3Akaggle.com%20Heart%20rate%20Variability&sxsrf=ALeKk00LShhM5-h5eVGV1lVlvlx0otOhHw%3A1621433713546&ei=cR2lYLzdIOuMjLsPq42M0Ag&oq=site%3Akaggle.com%20Heart%20rate%20Variability&gs_lcp=Cgdnd3Mtd2l6EANQzrIBWM6yAWC4tAFoAHACeACAAdsBiAHbAZIBAzItMZgBAKABAqABAaoBB2d3cy13aXrAAQE&sclient=gws-wiz&ved=0ahUKEwj82Zak99XwAhVrBmMBHasGA4oQ4dUDCA4&uact=5), and [Salomon Tetelepta codes](https://www.kaggle.com/stetelepta/exploring-heart-rate-variability-using-python):

[image]

So if possible I like to find out have all the shared codes via the Kaggle site [the APACHE 2.0 license](https://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0.html) and if not how much change on one code needs to change the main license?